# file.py просто открывается, вместо того что бы выполнится

Tags: python

почему когда я пытаюсь выполнить file.py через командную строку, он не выполняется,
а просто открывается в блокноте?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: потому что для расширения py у Вас привязан блокнот. Запускайте просто как `python python.py` или привяжите питон по расшиению

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вы создали файл с именем `python.py`, но формат у него является `.txt`

Чтобы это исправить можно переписать формат через проводник Windows,

заменив его с `.txt` на `.py`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если при переименовании файла у вас нет названия формата, включить его можно через:

- Вид
- Расширение имен файла

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У ТС точно всё с расширениями нормально, потому что бы он иначе файл из консоли не открыл.

Comment: я думаю, автор ответа намекает, что возможно, у автора вопроса на самом деле файл называется `python.py.txt`